# Read more than one text file for a foreach loop in Ant and store the line values as different properties

Tags: ant, foreach, ant-contrib

I have a requirement with respect to ant loops.

It says I have 3 different text files each with say 3 lines (each line is a one word string for all files).

Now I need a foreach loop in Ant that reads all 3 files at same time for the first line in each file and stores the values accordingly as 3 different properties. This way for every single iteration of loop I can refer to a target where I can pass these properties for target execution.

The loop will hence run 3 times and execute that target 3 times one for each iteration.

Say for example I have the following sample code:-

```
<target name="read">
<loadfile property="file" srcfile="./dist/DB_Critical_Stub_Data.txt"/>
<loadfile property="fileversion" srcfile="./dist/version.txt"/>
<loadfile property="filecomponent" srcfile="./dist/component.txt"/>
<foreach list="${file},${fileversion},${filecomponent}" param="line,line1,line2" delimiter="${line.separator}" target="start-stub"/>
 </target>
 <target name="start-stub">
  <property name="stub-name" value="${line}"/>
  <property name="stub-version" value="${line1}"/>
  <property name="stub-component" value="${line2}"/>
  <startStub name="${stub-name}" version="${stub-version}" component="${stub-component"}/>
</target>
```

Any suggestions/help here would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Let say i have 3 text files each with 3 lines and each line is a single word(number of lines in the files could be anything but same for all files, so all files will have same number of lines).
Let first file has below 3 lines:-
stub1
stub2
stub3

Second file has:-
ver1
ver2
ver3
Third one has:-
comp1
comp2
comp3

Now i would like an ant loop or something that can pick first line from each file and pas them as parameter to my destination target as part of first iteration. Then second line from each for second iteration and so on.

Comment: Whatever you are trying to do is much un-Ant like. for your requirement you shall use [script](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/script.html) tag with your preferred language.